# Android configuration changes and calling requestLayout - why doesn't it work?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-configchanges

In Android activities, we can manually handle a configuration change (e.g., orientation, screen size) by setting `android:config` and implementing `onConfigurationChanged` - typically, we would update the UI based on the new configuration.

I am trying to implement this functionality, and initially I thought it would just be calling `requestLayout` on the parent container - which should do a relayout and measure the new sizes based on the new configuration - however, that doesn't seem to do anything. My layout is unchanged even though I have custom values for font size, etc., based on the new configuration. Why doesn't that work? I want to re-layout the UI without having to manually set each attribute or re-create the entire UI (it's an expensive UI to build so I don't want to restart the activity)

Comment: "I have custom values for font size, etc., based on the new configuration" - these are values you've defined in resource XML files? What makes you think that anything other than inflating XML would cause XML files to be read?